# How to sign a SQL Server assembly created with assembly_bits / hex bytes?

Tags: security, assemblies, sql-server-2017, sqlclr, sql-server-2019

I'm working on an upgrade to SQL Server 2019 and I need to sign assemblies. However, the assembly code I have is using assembly_bits / hex bytes. I cannot find a good way to sign this assembly. How can this assembly be signed?

Below is a non-working example for reference:

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY HelloWorld  
    FROM 0x4D5A900000000000  
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, there is a way that's not very difficult. You can sign the assembly in-place, once it has been created. In order to create an unsigned assembly, you will need to *temporarily* enable the `TRUSTWORTHY` database setting, which will be disabled moments later.

The steps are as follows:

1. `ALTER DATABASE [{db_name}] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;`
2. Load one or more assemblies:

   ```sql
   CREATE ASSEMBLY HelloWorld
   FROM 0x4D5A900000000000
   WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
   ```
3. `ALTER DATABASE [{db_name}] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;`
4. Create a certificate to sign the assembl(y|ies):

   ```sql
   CREATE CERTIFICATE [HelloWorldAssemblies]
       ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '{choose your own password}'
       WITH
           SUBJECT = 'Support loading HelloWorld while avoiding TRUSTWORTHY',
           EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-12-31';
   ```
5. Copy certificate (public key only) to `[master]` DB:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @TempCRT NVARCHAR(MAX) =
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(N'HelloWorldAssemblies')), 1);

   EXEC (N'USE [master];
           CREATE CERTIFICATE [HelloWorldAssemblies]
           FROM BINARY = ' + @TempCRT);
   ```
6. Create login from the certificate AND grant it the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission:

   ```sql
   EXEC (N'USE [master];
   CREATE LOGIN [HelloWorldAssemblies]
       FROM CERTIFICATE [HelloWorldAssemblies];

   GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO  [HelloWorldAssemblies];');
   ```
7. Sign the assembl(y|ies):

   ```sql
   ADD SIGNATURE 
       TO ASSEMBLY::[HelloWorld]
       BY CERTIFICATE [HelloWorldAssemblies]
       WITH PASSWORD = '{choose your own password}';
   ```

I have a blog post describing this process, including a link to a walk-through demo script:
[SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 4: “Trusted Assemblies” – The Disappointment (Msg 10314)](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/28/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-4-trusted-assemblies-the-disappointment/)

Comment: I find that even when the database is set to `TRUSTWORTHY`, I cannot create the unsafe assembly - I get an error saying the `CREATE` faled because the assembly is not trusted. I can go ahead and make all the certification, but ultimately not apply the certificate to the non-existant assembly.... Is there a simple way around this that I missed?